# Program in Python that will prompt the user to enter an account number consists of 7 digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm taking an intro Python course and a little stuck on an assignment. Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the problem:
Write a program in Python that will prompt the user to enter an account number consists of 7 digits.

After getting that account number from user, verify if the account is valid or not. You should have a list called current_accts that hold all valid accounts.

Current valid accounts are shown below and you must use them in your program.

5679034   8232322   2134988    6541234   3984591   1298345   7849123    8723217

Verifying the account number entered should be done in a function called check_account() that will accept the account entered by the user and also the list current_accts. This function should return a 1 if account is valid otherwise return 0 if account is not valid.

Here's what I've written so far, but I'm stuck and also receiving syntax errors for indentation in lines 6-15. I'm also receiving error messages saying that variable 'current_accts' is not defined.

```
prompt = "Please, enter the 8 digit account  number: "
current_accts = current_accts[1:]
current_accts [-1] = "valid"


while True: 
    try:
      userinput = current_accts(prompt)
      if len(userinput ) > 8:
        raise ValueError()
      userinput = int(userinput)
    except ValueError:
     print('The value must be an 8 digit integer. Try again')
    else:
        break 

userinput = str(userinput)

a =int(userinput[7])+int(userinput[5])+int(userinput[3])+int(userinput[1])
b1 = str(int(userinput[6])*20)
b2 = str(int(userinput[4])*20)
b3 = str(int(userinput[2])*20)
b4 = str(int(userinput[0])*20)
y = int(b1[0])+int(b1[1])+int(b2[0])+int(b2[1])+int(b3[0])+int(b3[1])+int(b4[0])+int(b4[1])

x = (a+y)

if x % 10 == 0:
   print('The account number you entered is valid!')
else:
   print('The account number you entered is invalid!')
```

Comment: So what is the issue? Did you get an error? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting my variable 'current_accts' to be defined properly and also where to put the list of account numbers given to me in the assignment in my code.

Comment: ```where to put the list of account numbers``` - put them in a list at the top so the list will be available to everything below it.

Comment: ```receiving syntax errors for indentation``` - fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: If you are looking for cooked up code then please do not read the answer.

I can tell you the logic, I guess you are doing that wrong.

- Logic:

  1. Check whether the account number is 7 digit or not.
  2. if condition 1 is true then Check if it is in the list of given accounts or not.

You can check condition 1 by checking is the condition `1000000<= user_input <10000000`.

You can check the condition 2 by looping through the list.

Answer (score 0):

You really have to go back and learn some of the basic syntax of python, because there are many problems with your code. Just google for python tutorials, or google specific issues, like how to get a user's input in python.

Anyway, I don't mean to insult, just to teach, so here's my solution to your problem (normally i wouldn't solve all of it, but clearly you made some effort):

```
current_accts = ['5679034', '8232322', '2134988', '6541234', '3984591', '1298345', '7849123', '8723217']
user_input = input("Please, enter the 7 digit account  number: ")
if user_input in current_accts:
    print('The account number you entered is valid!')
else: 
    print('The account number you entered is invalid!')
```

I didn't place it in a function that returns 0 or 1 like your question demanded, I suggest you adapt this code to make that happen yourself